# dropdown menu with same classes

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have created a simple dropdown menu which shows a ul when the the a tags is hovered on. But as Some ebook titles return 2 listings this is proving a pain as both of them get the hover state when one is being hovered on. I hear using "this" will select the just the one I am hovering on but I can't quite get it right. This is what I have so far which works nicely when there is just 1 ebook title available.

```
<a class="button ebook-button" style="width: 150px;">Get the E-book ...</a>
<ul class='ebookRollover'>
    <li><a href='1'>1</a></li>
    <li><a href='2'>2</a></li>
    <li><a href='3'>3</a></li>
    <li><a href='4'>4</a></li>
    <li><a href='5'>5</a></li>
    <li><a href='6'>6</a></li>
</ul>
<a class="button ebook-button" style="width: 150px;">Get the E-book ...</a>
<ul class='ebookRollover'>
    <li><a href='1'>1</a></li>
    <li><a href='2'>2</a></li>
    <li><a href='3'>3</a></li>
    <li><a href='4'>4</a></li>
    <li><a href='5'>5</a></li>
    <li><a href='6'>6</a></li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.ebook-button').parent().css('padding-bottom', '0');
    $('.ebookRollover').hide()
    $('.ebook-button, .ebookRollover').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.ebookRollover').show()
        $('.ebook-button').addClass('active');
    });
    $('.ebook-button, .ebookRollover').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.ebookRollover').hide();
        $('.ebook-button').removeClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you please create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking, but what you have can easily be done in pure css like this: http://jsfiddle.net/p9v0j0he/

Comment: Thanks Marcel, that works well. The problem I was having was when the same button appeared twice on the page the dropdown menu was opening for both buttons despite only 1 obviously being hovered over. I saw that using (this) keyword instead of selecting the class would only activate the hover state on the button you were hovering on. But still i had problems with this as the dropdown would vanish when you try and hover on it. Your way seems ideal I will try and work that into sass in abit. Thanks for your response!